# Handle string to array conversion in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file(csv) which when read in spark dataframe has the below values for print schema

```
-- list_values: string (nullable = true)
```

the values in the column list_values are something like:

```
[[[167, 109, 80, ...]]]
```

Is it possible to convert this to array type instead of string?

I tried splitting it and using code available online for similar problems:

```
df_1 = df.select('list_values', split(col("list_values"), ",\s*").alias("list_values"))
```

but if I run the above code the array which I get skips a lot of values in the original array i.e.

output of the above code is:

```
[, 109, 80, 69, 5...
```

which is different from original array i.e. (-- 167 is missing)

```
[[[167, 109, 80, ...]]]
```

Since I am new to spark I don't have much knowledge how it is done (For python I could have done ast.literal_eval but spark has no provision for this.

So I'll repeat the question again :

How can I convert/cast an array stored as string to `array` i.e.

```
'[]' to [] conversion
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose your DataFrame was the following:

```python
df.show()
#+----+------------------+
#|col1|              col2|
#+----+------------------+
#|   a|[[[167, 109, 80]]]|
#+----+------------------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

You could use [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) to remove the leading and trailing square brackets. Once that's done, you can `split` the resulting string on `", "`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, regexp_replace

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "col3",
    split(regexp_replace("col2", r"(^\[\[\[)|(\]\]\]$)", ""), ", ")
)
df2.show()

#+----+------------------+--------------+
#|col1|              col2|          col3|
#+----+------------------+--------------+
#|   a|[[[167, 109, 80]]]|[167, 109, 80]|
#+----+------------------+--------------+

df2.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

If you wanted the column as an array of integers, you could use cast:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df2 = df2.withColumn("col3", col("col3").cast("array<int>"))
df2.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: The  method (regex replacement works like a charm) and then casting to array of integers works for me. Upvoted the answer for correctly solving the issue. 
Thanks

Comment: @kunal there's only one method here. The casting is an optional 2nd step if you wanted to transform the resultant split array from an array of strings into an array of ints. You *could* also combine them into one step: `split(regexp_replace("col2", r"(^\[\[\[)|(\]\]\]$)", ""), ", ").cast("array<int>")`. Again, it's up to you depending on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Hey pault .. I am assuming the regex would take care of the replacement and the second step would replace the newly created column to array of integers ?

Comment: @kunal yes. If you notice, I overwrote `col3` in the last step. It's doing the `cast` on the result of the regex+split.

Comment: I guess `trim(BOTH '[]' col2)` will be more efficient than `regexp_replace`

Comment: On second though, I don't think it's available in the [`pyspark.sql` API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=trim#pyspark.sql.functions.trim); the [SQL API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#trim) is more flexible in this case