# Casting string like "[1, 2, 3]" to array

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.3

Pretty straightforward. I have an array-like column encoded as a string (`varchar`) and want to cast it to `array` (so I can then `explode` it and manipulate the elements in "long" format).

The two most natural approaches don't seem to work:

```
-- just returns a length-1 array with a single string element '[1, 2, 3]'
select array('[1, 2, 3]')

-- errors: DataType array is not supported.
select cast('[1, 2, 3]' as array)
```

The ugly/inelegant/circuitous way to get what I want is:

```
select explode(split(replace(replace('[1, 2, 3]', '['), ']'), ', '))
-- '1'
-- '2'
-- '3'
```

(`regexp_replace` could subsume the two `replace` but regex with square brackets are always a pain; `ltrim` and `rtrim` or `trim(BOTH '[]'...)` could also be used)

Is there any more concise way to go about this? I'm on Spark 2.3.1.

Comment: I don't think there's a more concise way- use `regexp_replace()` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995057/5858851). In your case you can use: `explode(split(regexp_replace("a", r"(^\[)|(]$)", ""), ", ").cast("array<int>"))`

Comment: @pault thanks... I promise I scoured the `[apache-spark-sql]` tag for about 20 minutes and couldn't find that... I added `cast` there for good measure. Anyway it seems I'm out of luck :\

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming here that the elements are digits.  But you get the idea

```
>>> s = '[1,2,3]'
>>> list(c for c in s if c.isdigit())    
['1', '2', '3']

>>> map(int, list(c for c in s if c.isdigit()))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: this looks like pure Python code?

Comment: @MichaelChirico . Does it work in Spark?