# Add new column to dataframe depending on interqection of existing columns with pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe which consists of two columns

```
+--------------+------------+
|             A|           B|
+--------------+------------+
|       [b,  c]|   [a, b, c]|
|           [a]|      [c, d]|
|       [a,  c]|   [b, c, e]|
|       [b,  c]|      [a, b]|
|           [a]|   [a, d, e]|
|       [a,  c]|         [b]|
+--------------+------------+
```

Schema:

```
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to add a new column which must be O if the intersection of A and B is empty list ([]) and 1 otherwise.
I tried the code below but it seem incorrect at all

```
df.withColumn('Check', when (list((set(col('A'))&set(col('B')))) !=[] , 0).otherwise(1)).show()
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to add a new column which must be O if the intersection of A and B is empty list ([]) and 1 otherwise.

You can directly use array_intersect with `size` and `when+otherwise`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn("Check",(F.size(F.array_intersect("A","B"))!=0).cast("Integer")).show()
```

or:

```
df.withColumn("Check",F.when(F.size(F.array_intersect("A","B"))==0,0).otherwise(1)).show()
```

---

```
+------+---------+-----+
|     A|        B|Check|
+------+---------+-----+
|[b, c]|[a, b, c]|    1|
|   [a]|   [c, d]|    0|
|[a, c]|[b, c, e]|    1|
|[b, c]|   [a, b]|    1|
|   [a]|[a, d, e]|    1|
|[a, c]|      [b]|    0|
+------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. However it shows me this message array: cannot resolve 'array_intersect(`values`, `values2`)' due to data type mismatch

Comment: are those arrays in the column or string? can you please print schema and post in the body of the question?

Comment: Yes it's my fault because the column A is String. I must convert it to list. Thank you

Comment: @Mus no worries something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994340/handle-string-to-array-conversion-in-pyspark-dataframe) might help you or if you are in control of the input and change the type before consuming  thats great then :)